# GNU as: how to load a .bss/.data symbol to a register?

Tags: assembly, gnu, armv7, binutils

My problem is very basic. I'm making my first bare-metal program in assembler. The architecture is ARMv7-M and I'm using GNU as and I'm writing in UAL.

I have a variable in .bss (or .data, doesn't matter) declared as follows:

```
.lcomm a_variable, 4
```

Then I want to read its value somewhere in the program. For that I first load its address into a register and then load the value of the variable itself into another register:

```
adr     r0, a_variable
ldr     r1, [r0, #0]
```

So far so good. The compiled object contains my *a_variable* symbol:

```
00000000 b a_variable
```

And the generated instructions look like this:

```
0:  f2af 0004   subw    r0, pc, #4
4:  6801        ldr     r1, [r0, #0]
```

**The problem** begins when I want to link the object into resulting image. ld relocates *a_variable* symbol into the final .bss section at a new address:

```
20001074 b a_variable
```

But the final code **remains the same** and the program really tries to read *a_variable* from address 0x0 but not from 0x20001074.

I expect that ld somehow substitutes the new address because it seems to do so when you link objects compiled by GCC. I mean if I write a piece of C code doing something similar:

```
static int a_variable;
void foo(void)
{
    a_variable = 5;
}
```

...then I get the following instructions in the object file:

```
0:  f240 0300   movw    r3, #0
4:  f2c0 0300   movt    r3, #0
8:  2005        movs    r0, #5
a:  6018        str r0, [r3, #0]
```

...but the final image looks like this:

```
800c:       f242 338c       movw    r3, #9100       ; 0x238c
8010:       f2c0 0301       movt    r3, #1
8014:       2005            movs    r0, #5
8016:       6018            str     r0, [r3, #0]
```

So ld appears to have substituted the real address for the placeholder which as left.

My question is why doesn't this work in case of hand-written assembler code? What do I miss?

Comment: The ADR instruction only works with labels in the same section. The assembler or linker should have generated an error.

Comment: Mmm, it didn't. Maybe this is because a_variable and adr instruction are not very far from each other (actually both have the same 0 address) before linkage?

Comment: I think it's just a bug. The assembler gives the an error in ARM mode: `Error: symbol .bss is in a different section`. Does your code need to be position independent?

Comment: I guess no. It's just an application I only want to run on my stm32f4 mcu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ADR instruction only works when used with a nearby symbol (+/- 4095 in Thumb2 mode) defined in the same section and source file. The GNU assembler should have given an error for referencing the symbol in a different section. In ARM mode your code generates a `Error: symbol .bss is in a different section` error, but there's apparently a bug in how GAS handles the ADR instruction in Thumb mode that causes it silently accept it.

Instead you can either use the LDR or MOVW/MOVT instructions to load an arbitrary 32-bit constant, including addresses, into a register. The LDR instruction will put the address into a constant pool and load it from there, while the MOVW/MOVT instructions form the constant in two step, just like with your compiler. The former instruction only takes 6 bytes (2 for the instruct, 4 for the constant), the later two instructions take 8 bytes.  For example:

```
    .syntax unified
    .arch armv7-m
    .code 16

    .bss
    .lcomm a_variable, 4

    .text

    ldr     r1, =a_variable
    movw    r2, #:lower16:a_variable
    movt    r2, #:upper16:a_variable
```

Which when assembled, linked and disassembled gives:

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabi-as -o test.o test.s
$ arm-linux-gnueabi-ld -Tbss=f0000000 test.o
arm-linux-gnueabi-ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000010074
$ arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump -d a.out
...    
00010074 <.text>:
   10074:       4902            ldr     r1, [pc, #8]    ; (10080 <__bss_start-0x10f80>)
   10076:       f240 0200       movw    r2, #0
   1007a:       f2cf 0200       movt    r2, #61440      ; 0xf000
   1007e:       0000            movs    r0, r0
   10080:       f0000000        .word   0xf0000000
```

Comment: :lower16: and :upper16: - that was the thing I needed! In fact I knew about movw and movt instructions by I had no idea how to connect GAS labels to them. As to ldr... actually I had tried it too but I hadn't noticed that assembler stored another .word in .text section (in your example at address 10080) containing the address. So now both ways work fine for me. Thank you! The only bizarre thing is adr. With it I still get wrong code.

Comment: Hm. ldr saves you one byte in comparison with movw/movt. So from the first glance it seems more preferable.