# Segmentation fault when STR to a memory location pointed by label in ARM assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, gnu

Its just the second day of my learning ARM assembly and I am stuck at a problem where I get segmentation fault at STR.

```
@P = Q+R+S
@Q=2, R=4, S=5

.global main
main:
    adrl r4,vals
    ldr r1,[r4,#Q] @load Q=2 into r1
    ldr r2,[r4,#R]
    ldr r3,[r4,#S]
    add r0,r1,r2
    add r0,r0,r3
    str r0,[r4,#P]
    mov r7,#1
    svc 0

.equ P,0
.equ Q,4
.equ R,8
.equ S,12

vals:   .space 4
    .word 2
    .word 4
    .word 5
    .align
    .end
```

can someone please help as why its crashing?

**EDIT**

I add the variables to the data section.

```
@P = Q+R+S
@Q=2, R=4, S=5
.data
vals:   .space 4
    .word 2
    .word 4
    .word 5
    .align

.text
.global main
main:
    adrl r4,vals
    ldr r1,[r4,#Q] @load Q=2 into r1
    ldr r2,[r4,#R]
    ldr r3,[r4,#S]
    add r0,r1,r2
    add r0,r0,r3
    @str r0,[r4,#P]
    mov r7,#1
    svc 0

.equ P,0
.equ Q,4
.equ R,8
.equ S,12
.end
```

Compiling and linking like below :

```
$ as -o main.o main.s
main.s: Assembler messages:
main.s:13: Error: symbol .data is in a different section
```

Comment: Looks like `vals:` is in the .text section, which ends up in read-only memory pages.  Stores fault on addresses in read-only pages.

Comment: Try to use `.data` before `vals` to switch into the data segment.  If no section is selected, the assember defaults to assembling into the `.text` section.

Comment: @fuz: I tried that already but it was still crashing. Let me add that to the EDIT

Comment: @InsaneCoder No, you did not.  What you tried was putting everything into the data section.  This doesn't work as the data section is not executable.  `main` must go into the `.text` section so it can be executed.  Also, you might want to remove the `.end` directive.  Normally it indicates the end of an assembly file, but I'm not super sure about this.  In any way, it is not useful to have here.

Comment: @fuz : oops my mistake... I pasted an older version of the code. My latest version had those fixes. Let me edit it.

Comment: @InsaneCoder At least it's not crashing anymore!  Try to replace `adrl r4, vals` with `ldr r4, =vals` as per  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31707485/417501).

Comment: @fuz. Thanks. It worked. I also analyzed the memory location through gdb and the result is getting stored at the location. Can you please post this as answer.

Comment: @InsaneCoder Would you mind writing it up yourself?  I'm currently a bit busy doing other things.

Answer (score 2):

The segmentation fault happens because the `vals` is by default assembled into the text section, hence becoming non-writable.

The solution is to define `vals` in the data section like below :

```
@P = Q+R+S
@Q=2, R=4, S=5
.data
vals:   .space 4
    .word 2
    .word 4
    .word 5
    .align

.text
.global main
main:
    ldr r4,=vals
    ldr r1,[r4,#Q] @load Q=2 into r1
    ldr r2,[r4,#R]
    ldr r3,[r4,#S]
    add r0,r1,r2
    add r0,r0,r3
    @str r0,[r4,#P]
    mov r7,#1
    svc 0

.equ P,0
.equ Q,4
.equ R,8
.equ S,12
.end
```

Also `adrl r4,vals` is replaced with `ldr r4,=vals` because `adrl` cannot be used to refer label in a different section, as it may break.

Comment: The distance between sections is fixed at link time; unless you have a lot of total code and/or data, the distance should be within range for `adrl` (+- 1MiB for Thumb2, or +-256kiB for ARM mode with a word-aligned target address.)  http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204j/Cacecdga.html.   (It's normal that .text and .data get linked without a huge gap between them, I think.)  But according to your question, it seems your assembler rejects it as assemble time :/  Anyway yes, `ldr reg, =symbol` always works, at least if you don't need position-independent code.